# export excel taking long time from ASP pages?

Tags: asp-classic

I am using following code to export an excel spreadsheet from a `.asp` page.

```
 GMID = Request.QueryString ("GMID")
 Response.Buffer = False
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
 DIR_YR = Request.QueryString ("DIR_YR")
 CD = Request.QueryString("CD")
 YEAR = Request.QueryString("IND")
```

The problem is that when there are around 2,000 or more rows, the export to excel asks for an open option. When I click on that option, a "Download in progress..." is shown, but no excel file pop-up will open. This is a problem with only one sales rep who has more than 2000 rows.

How can I fixed this bug because for 700-800 rows it's working fine.

Comment: ASP.NET ot classic ASP?

Comment: ASP classic basically ASP pages

Comment: classic ASP ...................

Answer (score 0):

just change Response.Buffer =  false to true and it work